# Optimizing MySQL Query With Complicated Predicate

Tags: mysql

Thanks for trying to help.  I have a table called posts where there is a row for each post.  A post has a post_date (in unix timestamp format) and an author_id.

I am trying to get the number of unique authors that posted 5 or more times within a month grouped by month and year.

The query I have now for unique authors by month and year (without the filter for 5 or more posts within that month) is:

```
select
    month(from_unixtime(p.post_date)) as month,
    year(from_unixtime(p.post_date)) as year,
    count(distinct p.author_id)
from posts p
group by month,year
order by year desc,month desc
```

Can you please help me add a filter that will only count authors that had 5 or more posts in that given month?

**UPDATE**

The following query works but is extremely slow, even when adding predicates for just this month and year.  Can someone think of a better way to do it?

```
select
    month(from_unixtime(p.post_date)) as month,
    year(from_unixtime(p.post_date)) as  year,
    count(distinct p.author_id)
from posts p 
   where (
     select count(*) from posts p2 where p2.author_id=p.author_id
     and month(from_unixtime(p.post_date))=month(from_unixtime(p2.post_date))
     and year(from_unixtime(p.post_date))=year(from_unixtime(p2.post_date))
   )>=5
 group by month,year order by year desc,month desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use having count >5 .It will solve the problem

```
  select month(from_unixtime(p.post_date)) as month,
    year(from_unixtime(p.post_date)) as year,
    count( p.author_id) c from posts p 
    group by author , month,year having c >5 
    order by year desc,month desc
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just reding that wrong, but won't count return the number of unique authors?

Comment: That makes more sense, glad I'm not losing my mind :)  However, now the question is how to find the authors who have posted 5 times (IOW, 5 rows with the same author) in a single month. I have no idea how to do it, so I'll be interested to see how this gets solved.

Comment: This gives the number of posts that month and is the same results if you change it to count(p.post_date).  I want the number of unique authors who posted 5 or more times that month.